# How can I set a View as a default view in only imported solution in CRM(Dynamics 365)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I wanted to set a view as a default view in imported solution. I set it through

Settings-->Solutions-->selected the imported solution-->Open the solution by click on it-->Under Entities section-->Accounts-->Views-->Selected the View which I want to set as default-->From More Actions command, I have selected the "Set Default" option.

By this, selected view got default in both imported solution and enterprise crm version. Can any body tell me, how can I set the only in imported solution If I wanted to set the one view as default view, how it can be done?

Comment: You want the view to be set as default but not to be the default one ? Did I get it right ?

Comment: I want to set the view as default one for my customized application not for crm enterprise one. When I'm making a view as default one its also getting become as default one in enterprise crm as well. I want to set it as default, but not for enterprise.

Comment: I think I got it: that's not possible, default views are system-wide settings